# what is wrong with my code ? i wanted to see the transformations i did instead getting the error meassage

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting attribute error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'suffix'

```
credit_risk_transform=credit_risk[num_list].copy()

squared=(credit_risk_transform**2).add.suffix("squared")

square_root=(credit_risk_transform**0.5).add.suffix("_sqrt")

natural_log=np.log(credit_risk_transform+1).add,suffix("_ln")

credit_risk_transform=pd.concat([credit_risk_transform,squared,square_root,natural_log],axis=1)

credit_risk_transform.drop(['default_squared','default__sqrt','default_ln'],axis=1,inplace=True)

credit_risk_transform.head()
```

I wanted to see the transformations I did instead getting the error message

Answer (score 0):

this is the function you are using wrong

```
add_suffix("squared")
```

Answer (score 0):

`add.suffix()` means you are calling the suffix function of add attribute. Use `add_suffix("squared")` instead.